# Multipage react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am having troubles to render different components on on diff URL.

In the app views are rendered with node on server, but for some reason it shows the same page for any url.

app.js

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var Router = require('react-router').Router;
var Route = require('react-router').Route;
var hashHistory = require('react-router').hashHistory;

var MyApp = require('./components/MyApp.react');
var Test = require('./components/Test.react');

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={MyApp}/>
    <Route path="/test" component={Test}/>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('myapp-app')
);
```

MyApp.react.js

```
var React = require('react');

module.exports = MyApp = React.createClass({
render: function(){
return (<div>home</div>)
      }
    });
```

Test.react.js

```
var React = require('react')
module.exports = Test = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (<div>test</div>)
  }
});
```

server.js

```
var app = express();    
...here i omit other settings...
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/test', routes.test);
```

routes.js

```
module.exports = {
  index: function(req, res) {
    res.render('home',{
        markup:ReactDOMServer.renderToString(MyApp())
      }
    );
},
  test: function(req,res){
    res.render('test',{
        markup:ReactDOMServer.renderToString(Test())
      }
    );
  }
}
```

home.handlebars

```
<div>{{{markup}}}</div>
```

test.handlebars

```
<div>{{{markup}}}</div>
```

Things work for me, but each time for both - / and /test i get same - home page...

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using something like react-router to take care of the routing?

Comment: @erichardson30, wht do u mean not using? I am tryin to use it, but it does not seem to work or i am doing somethin wrong.

Comment: If you're not building a universal application, there is no need to have an express server that is listening for routes. React-router handles all of that for you. Can you provide more complete files for app, myapp, and test?

Comment: @erichardson30, i need an express, app is doing remote calls to an external api. Id like to have those calls be handled on server, rather than client ajax calls. Ill update post as u asked.

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense. Even if you want to actually fetch the data on the server, you will still have to make a `get` call to the server at a particular route to trigger that data fetching and a promise will have to be returned to the client to let it know that it's complete. The express server shouldn't be listening at the route paths and shouldn't be rendering any markup...

Comment: @erichardson30, is there some way to have my planed schema workin? What am i doing wrong at the moment? How would i do same without server side rendering?

Comment: Why the given router does not render proper component?

Comment: Its cames out, with Router component links would look a different way. When home one to be http://localhost, test view url would be http://localhost:3000/test#/test?_k=p0tmuf. Am i right?